# Using a function to read in a file

Tags: c, file-io

I have the code below which compiles fine in xcode, but when I take it across to Microsoft Visual studio I get a bunch of errors.

```
    void openfile(int mapArray[MAX_HEIGHT][MAX_WIDTH], int *interest, int *dimension1, int *dimension2)
    { 
    int counter = 0;
    char buffer;
    int rowss, colss;
    *interest = 0;

    FILE *f;
    f = fopen(FILENAME, "r");
    if (f==NULL) {
            printf("Map file could not be opened");
            return 0;
    }


    // create char array the dimensions of the map
    fscanf(f, "%d %d" , dimension1, dimension2 );
    // printf("%d %d\n" , dimensions[0], dimensions[1]);


    // Reads the spaces at the end of the line till the map starts
    buffer=fgetc(f);
    while (buffer!='*') {
            buffer=fgetc(f);
    }

    // Read the txt file and print it out while storing it in a char array
    while (buffer!=EOF) {

            mapArray[rowss][colss]=buffer;

            colss++;

            // Count up the points of interest
            if (((buffer>64)&&(buffer<90))||(buffer=='@') ) {
                                    counter++;

                            }

            // resets column counter to zero after newline
            if (buffer=='\n') {
                    colss=0;
                    rowss++;
            }
            buffer=fgetc(f);
    }

    // Closes the file
    fclose(f);
    *interest=counter;

    }
```

Which parts are creating all the errors?
I get this list of errors when attempting to compile

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Post that list of errors. We can narrow the problem down faster that way.

Answer (score 0):

I see a few immediate problems. First, you're not initialising `rowss` or `colss` before you use them, hence they could contain *any* value.

Second, `fgetc()` returns an `int` so that you can detect end of file. By using a `char` to hold the return value, you're breaking the contract with the standard library.

Thirdly, you return a `0` if the filename couldn't be opened, despite the fact that the function is specified to return `void` (ie, nothing).

No doubt those are three of the errors the compiler picked up on, there may be others, and you should probably post the error list with your question for a more exhaustive analysis.

Comment: I must have been using a post C98 or whatever compiler because almost all of my errors were due to initializing variables somewhere other than at the very beginning of main or the functions, thanks a lot for your help.